# Webpack reference error between multiple entry points

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I have the following webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
    a:'./src/a.js',
    b:'./src/b.js'
 },
 output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
 }
```

the content of a.js is:

```
const MSG = "Can you see me?";
```

the content of b.js is:

```
console.log(MSG);
```

My index is loading both bundled scripts :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/a.bundle.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/b.bundle.js"></script>
```

Npm run build, babel-loader, and run task work just fine. However, the reference MSG is not define in the DOM :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: MSG is not defined
```

Even thou the script a.js does define it. Am I missing something here? Do I need extra configurations to access values between different entry points ?

Comment: It's not a global variable. It's scoped inside a function in the first entry point. You can export it from an and import it in b.

Comment: right... figure that much after actually reading the bundles, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in comments I needed to export - import the values which are defined in their respective module scope

a.js:

```
const MSG = "HEY CAN YOU SEE ME?";
module.exports = {
    MSG:MSG
};
```

b.js:

```
var MSG = require('./a.js').MSG;
console.log(MSG);
```